# PHP functions not working when not on local server

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, get

I'm trying to find if variables (using GET) exist using an if statement, but I can't get them to work on my web server, but my local server works fine.

I have if statements like these in my PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['typeQ']) && $_GET['typeQ'] == 4 && isset($_GET['searchQ'])){
        header("Location: schoolEdit.php?schoolid=".$_GET['searchQ']."");
    } else if(isset($_GET['typeQ']) && $_GET['typeQ'] == 5 && isset($_GET['searchQ'])){
        header("Location: vehicleEdit.php?vehicleid=".$_GET['searchQ']."");
    } else if(isset($_GET['typeQ']) && $_GET['typeQ'] == 6 && isset($_GET['searchQ'])){
        header("Location: driverEdit.php?driverid=".$_GET['searchQ']."");
    } else if(isset($_GET['typeQ']) && $_GET['typeQ'] == 3 && isset($_GET['searchQ'])){
        header("Location: studentEdit.php?studentid=".$_GET['searchQ']."");
    }
```

When I go to this URL on my localserver (http://localhost/voyageur/index2.php?searchQ=1&typeQ=6), it sees that "typeQ" is set as 6 and "searchQ" is set to something and runs the header code. But on my web server, it doesn't run any of these using the same type of URL, it just skips them as if none of them were set.

Is there something I need to configure on my web server to get this to work properly like I have it working locally?

Comment: In the beginning of your script, do a `<pre><?php print_r($_GET);` to see if the values are present in the `$_GET` array. Also, make sure error reporting is enabled: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: Does it not enter any `if` branch, or does it enter the branch but does not perform the redirect?

Comment: It doesn't enter any of those, no matter what values they are. It just skips them. 

There are no errors and it does in fact see both those vars with the print_r($_GET)

Comment: How have you tested whether it enters the branch? Have you tried to replace the redirect with a `print`? Also, you may try to print out the result of each evaluation.

Comment: I actually didn't think of that (been a long night), it appears as if it does go into the branch, but doesn't run the header() code.

Comment: And you are certain that you have `error_reporting` enabled? An error should be sent.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I created a php.ini file in there too with error_reporting  =  E_ALL and nothing happens. I'm now echoing $_GET['typeQ'] inside the branches and the correct value comes up (so I know it's getting inside the branch. One of the weirdest bugs I've seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have thought of this, but I got this to work by moving the if statements up higher in the code. Still strange how I didn't get "headers already sent" errors or something.

Thanks for the help everyone :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does [`headers_sent()`](http://php.net/headers_sent) return in the code you used before?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

header("Location: schoolEdit.php?schoolid=".$_GET['searchQ']."");

to

header("Location: schoolEdit.php?schoolid=".$_GET['searchQ']);

The header function on your server may be reading the header insert incorrectly since you're concatenated nothing to the end of your header. Hopefully, this will fix your problem. It's the only thing that I could find. Other than that, it looks sound.

Comment: Nope, didn't fix it. Good find though, not sure why those empty quotes were there in the first place.

Comment: Ha! Just saw your fix. I was just thinking about that!